# Let x_n be a bounded sequence. Deﬁne b_n := inf{x_k | k ≥ n}. Show that b_n is an increasing sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

It's a homework given by my lecturer and I don't know how to solve it. Will be glad if someone can give me some hints or tips or help me solve it... XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(b_{n})$ is increasing means that $m > n \Rightarrow b_{m} \ge b_{n}$.

$b_{m} = \inf_{k \ge m} x_{k}$

$b_{n} = \inf_{k \ge n} x_{k}$

Since $m>n$ is an hypothesis, what can you deduce on the sets $\{x_{k}/k \ge n\}$ and $\{x_{k}/k \ge m\}$ ?

Comment: What I don't understand is that let say x_n={-1,-2,0,1,2,3} (because he didnt mention that x_n is increasing)then b_1=inf{-1,-2,0,1,2}=-1 b_2=inf{-2,0,1,2}=-2 then b_n is not increasing?

Comment: b_1=inf{-1,-2,0,1,2}=-2 and not -1 :)
The "inf" of a set is the biggest number that is lower than all elements in the set.

Comment: ok... i will try to get it! thanks a lot by the way!

Comment: What I tried to emphasize in my previous comment is that **the "inf" of a set is the biggest number that is lower than all elements in the set.** If a set $A_{n}$ is contained in a set $A_{m}$, what can you deduce on their $inf$ ? :)

Comment: inf(Am)≥inf(An)?

Comment: It's the opposite actually. Now, in the problem, $m>n$ so $\{x_{k}/k \ge m\}$  is contained in $\{x_{k}/k \ge n\}$. As a consequence, $inf \{x_{k}/k \ge m\} \ge inf \{x_{k}/k \ge n\}$ so $b_{m} \ge b_{n}$, and that gives you the result you wanted ! :)

Comment: ok, get it, thanks! haha... XD

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint. Consider $b_1$ and $b_2$. By definition $b_2=\inf\{x_2,x_3,\ldots\}$.  Now examine the cases for $b_1$ when $x_1\geq b_2$ and $x_1<b_2$.

Comment: What I don't understand is that let say x_n={-1,-2,0,1,2,3} (because he didnt mention that x_n is increasing)then
b_1=inf{-1,-2,0,1,2}=-1
b_2=inf{-2,0,1,2}=-2
then b_n is not increasing?

Comment: Traklon beat me to the punch on this one, but I should also point something out. The use of the notation $x_n$ describes a mapping from the positive integers to the real numbers. It can't have a "final" element.

Comment: That being said, this still works for finite sequences. Think of it this way. As you increase your index from 1 to 2 (and so on), you are shrinking the size of the set under consideration.  But when determining $b_2$, you are removing one of the elements you used to determine $b_1$. Now matter which element you remove, $b_2$ cannot be less than $b_1$ (Why?)